# Avatar displayed Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display an image on my wordpress-theme depending on which author wrote the page.

Therefore I am doing this:

```
<img src="<?php $autor=the_author_meta('display_name'); 
if (strpos($autor,'foo') !== false) 
{echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/bilder/foo.jpg" />
<?php } else  {echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); }
        ?>/bilder/fun.jpg" />
```

But this is throwing several errors. It's a) not pointing to the right path by not using get_template_directory_uri() at all. And it's b) adding me the Authorname within the url now like this

```
http://domain.com/Author%Name/bilder/fun.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong? And I don't want to use a plugin therefore - but thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_author_meta()` is set to output the result, you want to just return it. So instead change it to `get_the_author_meta()`.

Also I've tidied up your code, as I think there were some errors in it.

```
<img src="<?php $autor = get_the_author_meta('display_name'); 
if (strpos($autor,'foo') !== false) {
    echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri())."/bilder/foo.jpg";
} else {
    echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri())."/bilder/fun.jpg";
} ?>" />
```

When I replace `foo` with my user name, the image path is displayed as /bilder/foo.jpg, when I change it back to anything that isn't my username, it's shown as /bilder/fun.jpg, so I believe it works fine. The template URL appears fine too.

`<img src="http://test.local/wp-content/themes/test/bilder/fun.jpg">`